# I cannot get alert with full name

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

I am trying to use variables and to get a box alert with the name, but it's not working.

I am learning variables in JavaScript at the moment, Stefan Mitchoock -StudioWeb course, and I already reached chapter 5 and the code from the course it's not working and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Many thanks for the help!

```
    </title>
    <script src="external.js"></script>

    <script>
    var firstName="Adina"
    var secondName="Avram"
    var fullName=firstName+secondName;

    function sniffer (message) {console.log("Event:"+message);alert("inside function alert");}
    alert("not in function code");


    </script>

    <style>


    </style>

    </head>

    <body id="bodyly">


    <nav id="navigation">


    </nav>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("butt").onclick=function(){sniffer("Clicked on secondP");outSide();}
   </script>

     </body>

     </html>




    and this is the external.js
    external.js


    function outSide(){alert("called: outSide()function");}

  Thank you a lot!
```

Comment: You're not using the variable `fullName` anywhere.

Comment: you mean I just declared the variable but I did not include in a function?

Comment: You don't have any button has id `butt`

Comment: I do, but I did not included here because the page said it's too much code

Comment: <button id="butt"> Try it</button>

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you never actually make use of the `fullName` that you are creating using `firstName` and `lastName`. Try something like this:

```
function sniffer (message) {console.log("Event:"+message);alert(fullName);}
```

And also, I'd recommend using multiple lines so it's easier to read. So something like this:

```
function sniffer (message) {
    console.log("Event:" + message);
    alert(fullName);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, the variable did work but I still need that pop up alert with the whole name

Comment: how I do that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: at the moment the variable it's working when I click the button, try it

Answer (score 0):

Since `fullName` is declared as a global variable (outside any function) you can directly access it anywhere within your code.

Check below:

**Note:** I purposefully added the `alert(fullName);` inside all the functions just to show the accessibility of the global variable.

```js
var firstName="Adina";
var secondName="Avram";
var fullName = firstName + " " + secondName;   // add a space between the names?

function sniffer(message) {
  console.log("Event: " + message);
  alert("inside function alert");
  alert("This is full name in sniffer " + fullName);
}

function outSide() {
  alert("called: outSide() function");
}

document.getElementById("butt").onclick = function() {
  sniffer("Clicked on secondP");
  outSide();
  alert("This is full name in the onclick listener " + fullName);
}
```

```html
<p id="butt">Click me</p>
```

---

**Edit:** Showing full example on a full HTML template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
  <script src="external.js"></script>
  <script>
    var firstName="Adina";
    var secondName="Avram";
    var fullName=firstName+secondName;

    function sniffer(message) {
      console.log("Event: " + message);
      alert("inside function alert");
      alert("This is full name in sniffer " + fullName);
    }
    alert("not in function code");
  </script>
</head>

<body id="bodyly">
  <nav id="navigation"></nav>
  <p id="butt">Click me</p>
  
  <script>
    document.getElementById("butt").onclick = function() {
      sniffer("Clicked on secondP");
      outSide();
      alert("This is full name in the onclick listener " + fullName);
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when I run the code here on the website, it's working, but not in my computer

Comment: @RalucaAdinaAvram What doesn't work? I'll check and edit, stay tuned.

Comment: @RalucaAdinaAvram try now

Comment: @RalucaAdinaAvram did it work? Let me know so I can explain what the issue was

Comment: nope, sorry, but I could use the explanation, it's working only if I click on the button Try it and I want the box to pop as the page has loaded, with the name Adina Avram

Comment: @RalucaAdinaAvram Ok, try now, I've added another answer with a full example of how that would look inside a full HTML document. Let me know if it works now (replace all your code with the bottom answer and let me know)